# Inserting into database on ViewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, ios11

I have an iOS app which uses a database hosted on a remote server.

Is it possible or just bad practice to perform a database INSERT inside the ViewWillDisappear function?

I can't seem to find much information on what operations Apple allows inside that function.

Comment: Bad practice and bad design. Operations such as that should be performed by a Model class not a view controller class. How are you even thinking this will work? What if the remote connection to the database takes 5 or 10 or 30 seconds to complete, then what were you planning on doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is bad practice for multiple reasons:

- inside the ViewController should be only functionality related to controlling the views
- the request to the server is asynchronous (I hope) so the view will be long gone when the result from the server comes. For example, if the response is an error, you will not have any way to display the message.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it returns an error but I understand - i thought it wasn't good practice.